# SSRS Matrix StdDevP not calculating correctly

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

I am having problems with getting the StdDevP function to work correctly on a total column (stddevp problem is highlighted in yellow).  It works correctly on the column group, but not on the total column.  It wants to create the standard deviation based on every cell in the group, not the standard deviation of just the total column.  I have tried various versions of "scope", but with no luck.  The same problem is with the Avg function on a total column.  It averages all cells in the matrix and not just the cells in the total column.  I think if I could find a way to find the scope of the "Total" Column, that it might solve my problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: What are the actual expressions you are using?

Comment: for the group/Std Dev cell:=stdevp(Fields!TicketCount.Value, "DOW")  and this works fine, but I have tried all kinds of different formulas to get the Std Dev on the total column and nothing works.